# pairing algorithm in R

Tags: r, monte-carlo, matching, genetic-algorithms

I have two sets of elements *M* and *N*, and a scalar-valued distance/similarity function between one element from *M* and one from *N*.  The problem is to generate a set of pairs (one item from *M* and one from *N*) which minimizes the sum of the distance function.

Caveats

- Using an existing package in R would be ideal
- *M* and/or *N* may contain "extra" elements that don't have a partner; therefore *M* and *N* may be of unequal length
- We have a starting configuration which is reasonably close

My first thought in addressing this is a monte carlo or genetic algorithm.  So perhaps as a solution someone could show how to use an R genetic algorithm package for this problem.

Also see [this unanswered question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49548/an-algorithm-for-pairing).

Comment: Some additional constraints are needed, for after all one can achieve a minimum sum of distances by choosing no elements from either set.  Do you intend that *all* elements in the smaller set have pairs?  If so, is the pairing supposed to be one-to-one? Is your function a true distance (that is, does it satisfy the reflexive, symmetric, and triangle inequality axioms)?

Comment: (1) Then function satisfies the reflexive, symmetric, and triangle inequality axioms (2) For starters I would like to require each element from the smaller list to be paired with an element from the larger list.  This is an applied rather than theoretical problem; make whatever assumptions we need to get a reasonable set of pairs.

Comment: Also, minimizing the distance function is not the ultimate goal, rather to generate a set of pairs.  I thought there might be a way to frame it as a GA problem in R if it was expressed this way.

Comment: If you have MxN matrix of distances, Hungarian algorithm (or some other linear programming aproach) will get you Q=min(M,N) pairs with absolute minimal the overall sum of within-pair distances. (There is also a [modification](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6870551/868905) allowing to request Q<min(M,N), - not very efficient wrt speed, but working.